# Minimize sum of the norm of cross products

Tags: linear-algebra, cross-product

Here I have an interesting problem on linear algebra. It looks very simple, but not so easy to solve for me.

Let $r_i, i=1,…,n$ be unit vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, find a unit vector $x$ to minimize
$\sum \| r_i\times x \|^2$

Remark: if let $\theta$ be the angle between $r_i$ and $x$, then $\sum \| r_i\times x \|^2 = \sum \sin^2 \theta _i$. But I don't like sinusoid functions, I think they make the problem more complex especially for high dimensional cases. Is it possible to solve the problem using linear algebra or matrix analysis?

Thank you very much.

Shiyu

Comment: What is the cross product in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Does $x=0$ solve your problem?

Comment: The $ \times$ means cross product. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product.

Comment: I forgot to add a constraint that $ x $ is a unit vector.

Comment: @Thomas: @Theo: OP has now called for $x$ to be a unit vector, so $x=0$ won't work, probably because of your comments.  I think the best way to view the request is $\sum \| r_i\times x \|^2 = \sum \sin^2 \theta _i=\sum 1-\cos^2 \theta_i=\sum 1-(r_i\cdot x)^2$

Comment: @Shiyu:  but the cross product is difficult to define in dimensions other than 3.  This is essentially because a 3x3 antisymmetric matrix has 3 independent components, but a 4x4 has 6, not 4.  The general case is n(n-1)/2.  That is why I went to the dot product, which is well defined.

Comment: @Ross: thanks, the two problems are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Ross: The edit happend just before I left my comment, that's why I removed it right afterwards. I think your interpretation sounds correct, but I think it shouldn't be phrased in terms of the cross product. @Shiyu: I don't see how they should be equivalent even if interpreted in terms of the generalization alluded to by Ross.

Comment: @Calle @Thomas: do you mean the cross product will have no geometric meaning when $n>3$? Ross gives an equivalent problem using inner product. Maybe it is better to use inner product to describe the problem.

Comment: @Shiyu:  lower on the Wikipedia page you cite there is a short bit on Cross product as an exterior product, which links to exterior product.  That will give you some idea what goes on in other dimensions.  It does have a meaning, but it is an n-2 dimensional object.

Comment: @Theo: Maybe it is better to show the most original problem. In fact, I am trying to find the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $A=\sum (Id-r_i r^T_i)$. As $\lambda_{min} = min x^T A x$ for arbitrary unit vector $x$, I am trying to minimize $x^T A x$ to get the minimum eigenvalue. In addition, I think it is straight forward to verify $\sum \| r_i\times x \|^2 = \sum 1-(r_i\cdot x)^2$

Comment: Do you have any condition on $r_i$, $i = 1, \dots, n$? Are they linearly independent? Orthogonal?

Comment: @Calle: No. $ r_i $ can be arbitrary unit vectors with $\|r_i\|^2=1$. It seems that the minimum eigenvalue of $A$ can not be determined analytically if $r_i$ are arbitrary even though the matrix $A$ has a very special form, right?

Comment: @Shiyu: Yeah. The eigenvalues of $I - r_ir_i^T$ are easy to determine, but the whole sum seems trickier.

Comment: @Calle: Yes, you are right. $Id-r_i r_i^T$ in fact is an orthogonal projection matrix with rank 2. Its eigenvalues are 1, 1 and 0. But the sum of some orthogonal projection matrices is a positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximize $\sum_i (r_i \cdot x)^2$ over unit vectors $x$.  To get rid of the constraint, this is $$\frac{\sum_i (r_i \cdot x)^2}{|x|^2}=\frac{\sum_i (r_i \cdot x)^2}{\sum_j x_j^2}=\frac{\sum_{ij} (r_{ij} x_j)^2}{\sum_j x_j^2}$$ where $r_{ij}$ is the $j^{th}$ component of $r_i$.  Now you can differentiate with respect to $x_j$ and set to zero without any trig functions getting in the way.

Comment: thanks. In fact, we can directly calculate the derivative of ${\sum (r^T_i x )^2}/{x^T x}$ with respect to the vector $x$. Let the derivative be zero and we have $x^T x\sum (r^T_i x )r_i-\sum(r^T_ix)^2x=0$.